# Commutative integral domain does not finitely generate its field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, finitely-generated

> I want to prove that if we have a commutative integral domain $D$ with field of fractions $F\neq D$ then $F$ is not finitely generated as a $D$-module. (In this question it may be the case that $1\not\in D$.)

My original plan was to localize at a maximal ideal and then use Nakayama's lemma but as we don't have a $1$ our localization may not be local (in fact we need not have maximal ideals).

So I'm a bit lost as to where to go?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When $F=D$ it is.

Comment: What is field of fraction of nonunital ring? I guess id add unit and then took filed of fraction. Thats what you mean?

Comment: @user52045  It is not necessary that we have a unit in order to create a field of fractions. The field of fractions are all $\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in R$. In the embedding we may just map elements of $R$ to $\frac{ax}{x}$ for some $x\in R$ if we have identity the $x=1$ but this is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac{a_i}{b_i}, 1\le i\le n$, be a generating set. Then 
$$\forall x\in D \ \ \exists c\in D \text{ such that } \frac{1}{x}=\frac{c}{a},$$
where $a=a_1\cdots a_n$, i.e.,
$$\forall x\in D \ \ \exists c\in D \text{ such that } cx=a.$$

For $x=a^2$ we have $ca=1$, so every $y\in D$ is invertible: if $ty=a$ then $cty=1$. Hence $D=F$.

Comment: I must be missing something. Don't you want to use $b = b_1 \dotsb b_n$?

Comment: How are you concluding every $y \in D$ is invertible. You let $x$ be arbitrary, but then you are choosing $x$ to be $a^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If the fractions $p_i/q$ ($i=1,2,\dots,n$) form a set of generators (it's not restrictive to assume the denominators are the same), then any element of $F$ can be written as
$$
\frac{x}{y}=\sum_{1\le i\le n}\frac{p_i}{q}d_i
=\frac{1}{q}\sum_{1\le i\le n}p_id_i
$$
which means $1/q$ is a generator. Since $F\ne D$, we have $1/q\notin D$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{q^2}=\frac{d}{q}
$$
for some $d\in D$, which means $dq=1$, a contradiction.

If $1\notin D$, we have that $\frac{q}{q^2}$ is a generator, but then
$$
\frac{q}{q^3}=\frac{qd}{q^2}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{q}{q^2}=q\frac{q}{q^3}=q\frac{qd}{q^2}=\frac{q^2d}{q^2}=d
$$
which is again a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have two very good answers, I'd like to (just for fun) note that this also follows from very basic commutative algebra.

You have an inclusion $D\hookrightarrow F$ which, by assumption, is finite. Then, by the Lying Over Theorem, we'd have a surjection $\text{Spec}(F)\to\text{Spec}(D)$ which implies that $\text{Spec}(D)$ has only one prime. This prime must be $(0)$, and since it's the only prime, it must be maximal. So, $D$ is a field, and so $D=F$.

EDIT: I just noticed the strange assumption that $D$ needn't haven't a unit. It seems strange then to call $D$ a 'domain' and $F$ a 'field', since these usually have (definitionally) unit. So, the above only works if $D$ is unital.