# Show that field of fraction of a commutative domain is an indecomposable module which is not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I came across this problem and get stuck for quite sometime.

**Problem:** Let $R$ be a commutative domain that is not a field. Let $F$ be its field of fractions. Show that $F$ is an indecomposable $R$-module which is not finitely generated.

**Attempt:** I did a similar problem before showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module that is not decomposable and not finitely generated. I think this problem feels like a generalization of what's happening in the rational number case. However, I don't know where to start.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you reason for Z? Why didn't it just work for the general case?

Comment: In case you want an answer: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598089/commutative-integral-domain-does-not-finitely-generate-its-field-of-fractions