# Is $\mathbb Q$ finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Is $\mathbb Q$ finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-module?

If I were to take a guess, I would say no but only because I am not sure how to generate all of $\mathbb Q$ from a finite set. But is this possible?

Comment: A $\mathbb{Z}$ module is the same as an Abelian group.

Comment: Hint: With finitely many generators, the denominators in the generated set stay bounded. Also, I'm quite sure this has been asked and answered here before.

Comment: Hint for a more advanced method: A finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-module is Noetherian. Now look at the $\Bbb Z$-submodules $(1/n) \subsetneq (1/n^2) \subsetneq ...$. -- To back up my other claim, here are answers to much more general questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598089/96384 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1937371/96384

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}$ is generated by $$\frac{p_1}{q_1},\ldots,\frac{p_k}{q_k}\in \mathbb{Q},$$
with $p_i,q_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k.$ Then show that
$$ \langle \frac{p_1}{q_1},\ldots,\frac{p_k}{q_k}\rangle \leq \langle \frac{1}{q}\rangle$$
where $q=q_1q_2\cdots q_k.$ Since every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic then
$$  \langle \frac{p_1}{q_1},\ldots,\frac{p_k}{q_k}\rangle=\langle \frac{m}{n}\rangle$$
for some $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}.$ But $\frac{m}{2n}\not\in\langle \frac{m}{n}\rangle$ and $\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q},$ so we reached a contradiction.

Comment: @i707107 I corrected it.